# Unable to close IONIC InAppBrowser for particular URL

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

> I am using Ionic with React or Capacitor I want close my InAppBrowser for any particular URL ....Thanks in advance.

```js
// open InAppBrowser w/out the location bar
var ref = window.open('http://myloginapp.com', '_self');

// attach listener to loadstart
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { 
    var urlSuccessPage = "http://myloginapp/success/";
    if (event.url == urlSuccessPage) {
    ref.close();    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at examples in the plugin [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#example).
It would seem that `loadstart` event doesn't contain a URL param. Try using `beforeloadCallBack` to detect the URL that's being loaded.

For example:

```
ref.addEventListener('beforeload', function(params, callback) { 
    var urlSuccessPage = "http://myloginapp/success/";

    if (params.url === urlSuccessPage ) {
        ref.close();
    } else {
        callback(params.url);
    }
 });
```

Also, make sure `window.open()` is indeed referencing InAppBrowser. You might need to use `window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open()`.

Comment: `var ref = InAppBrowser.create('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_self', 'location=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('beforeload', function(params, callback) { 
      console.log(params.url)
      var urlSuccessPage = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup";  
      if (params.url === urlSuccessPage ) {
          ref.close();
      } else {
          callback(params.url);
      }
   });`.    its not working for me

Comment: Can you share more information? Do you get any errors?